# Concatenated Label - Mat tab

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular10

In my Angular10 app, I have a tab group where each tab shows the user details. Currently I use the user ID as a label for the tab, but I want to display both the ID and the name for the user as a tab label. Pls suggest how I can concatenate the ID and name. Below is my code.

```
<mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs>
  <mat-tab *ngFor="let user of userArray" [label]="user.userId">
    <app-user></app-user>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: For complex labels you could use the included portal mat-tab-label it even supports custom formatting(https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api#MatTabLabel). There is also an official example with usage here: https://stackblitz.com/angular/nkbjxoxjdpd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try with

`<mat-tab *ngFor="let user of userArray" label="{{ user.userId }} {{ user.Name }}">`

Comment: Thanks that worked. But what is the difference between [label] and label. I tried the same thing with [label] but it gave error.     (Apologies, if the doubt appears daft, I am quite new to web development )

Comment: label is normal attribute, you just pass an ordinary string value. Here you are getting user from *ngFor. So label is okay.
[label] is ordinary label, with value binding from ts. If you have a variable and you need that value as label, do this.